# Make DFA of the set of all strings from {0,1} whose tenth symbol from the right end is a 1

Tags: dfa, computation

What will be the transition diagram of the set of all strings from {0,1} whose tenth symbol from the right end is a 1 ?
I know the regular expression is (0+1)*1(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)
But I couldn't turn it into DFA.

Comment: The point of the question is that it will be big. At least 512 states. That's  because it needs to "remember" it saw a 1 for 9 more characters that could be either 1 or 0. Design a machine that works for the 2nd-last character. Then for the 3rd-last. You'll see the pattern and be able to expand it to 9.

Comment: Can't i just transit state using 0,1 for last 9 and check the tenth-last? But if i do so, what the starting state will consume! As it's DFA i can't use 1 for the 11th-last in the self loop.

Comment: No. What you're describing is the NFA that solves the problem. If you do the NFA and then transform it to a DFA (using the subset construction), you'll see the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this question in `Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computations by John E. Hopcroft, Rajeev Motwani, Jeffrey D. Ullman`.

First, we need to get hold of the NFA here. This would have 11 states in linear formation with the start having a self loop with 0,1 and a transition to the next state with 1 (not 0). All the other 9 transitions from q<sub>i</sub> -> q<sub>i+1</sub> would have transition for 0,1 both. The last state, q<sub>10</sub> will be our accept state.

That was fairly a straightforward approach for the NFA. Now if we convert this NFA to a DFA considering all 2<sup>11</sup> subsets of set of states of the NFA, we would get the solution.

I will add the NFA Diagram when I get some time. And try to figure out an easy trick to solve the DFA without considering all the possibilities.

You can look at Example 1.30 from `Introduction to the Theory of Computation - M. Sipser - 3rd Edition` at page 51. There they showed an NFA for strings having 1 at the third position from the end would have 4 states but that corresponding DFA would have 8 states. Not posting the screenshots for copyright issues.

Answer (score 0):

DFA of the set of all strings from {0,1} whose tenth symbol from the right end is a ...

[image: DFA is represented in image below]

the regular expression for given language is :

```
        (0+1)*1(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)
```

Hope you got it..!!